Error verifying Metaplex NFT
Trying to verify a Metaplex NFT as part of a collection
Logs: 
[
  "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]",
  "Program log: IX: Verify",
  "Program log: Collection Not Found on Metadata",
  "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 14670 of 200000 compute units",
  "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x50"
]. 


Here is my code
const collectionAddress = UMIPublicKey("");

const metadata = findMetadataPda(umi, { mint: collectionAddress });
await verifyCollectionV1(umi, {
    metadata,
    collectionMint: collectionAddress,
    authority: umi.identity,
}).sendAndConfirm(umi);


I was forgetting to add the NFT that I wanted to verify and that's why I was getting the error.
The steps to verify a Metaplex collection are

Mint a collection NFT with the isCollection flag.

Mint an NFT as part of the collection.

verify the minted NFT as part of the collection.


const collectionAddress = UMIPublicKey("");
const nftAddress = UMIPublicKey("");

const metadata = findMetadataPda(umi, { mint: nftAddress });
await verifyCollectionV1(umi, {
    metadata,
    collectionMint: collectionAddress,
    authority: umi.identity,
}).sendAndConfirm(umi);


curl --request GET 
--url 'https://pro-api.solscan.io/v1.0/block/last?limit=10' 
--header 'content-Type: application/json' \
